# enviar 2 formularios con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

tengo 2 formularios iguales y me gustara que mi funcion en ajax funcione para los dos al mismo tiempo pero solo me toma en cuenta el primero, quiero saber como hago para que tome en cuenta el otro form

es un buscador de dominio, incresas el dominio y te dice si esta disponible o no, y coloco 2 forms iguales porque en el proyecto que tengo se van agregando de forma dinamica es decir pueden ser 1, 2 o mas forms

```html
<form style="margin-bottom:20px; ">
        <!--Creamos un input para guardar el nombre del dominio en una variable-->
            <input type="text"  id="Nomb" name="Nomb" placeholder="Dominio" style="border-right: none;">
        <!--Creamos una lista select para guardar la extencion del dominio en una variable-->
            <select  id="Ext" name="Ext">
                <option>.com</option>
                <option>.net</option>
                <option>.bo</option>
                <option>.mx</option>
                <option>.pe</option>
                <option>.co</option>
                <option>.name</option>
                <option>.org</option>
            </select>
            <button id="Enviar" type="button">Buscar</button>
        </form>
        <form style="margin-bottom:20px; ">
        <!--Creamos un input para guardar el nombre del dominio en una variable-->
            <input type="text"  id="Nomb" name="Nomb" placeholder="Dominio" style="border-right: none;">
        <!--Creamos una lista select para guardar la extencion del dominio en una variable-->
            <select  id="Ext" name="Ext">
                <option>.com</option>
                <option>.net</option>
                <option>.bo</option>
                <option>.mx</option>
                <option>.pe</option>
                <option>.co</option>
                <option>.name</option>
                <option>.org</option>
            </select>
            <button id="Enviar" type="button">Buscar</button>
        </form>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        //Creamos la variable Incremento y la igualamos a 0
        var Incremento = 0;
        //Seleccionamos el boton Enviar y creamos una funcion que se ejecutara al hacer click en el
        $(":input[type= 'text']").keyup(function(event) {
            // incrementamos la variable en 1 
            Incremento++;
            //Validamos si el usuario a ingresado el nombre del dominio
            if ($("#Nomb").val() == "") {
                $("#loader").html("<strong style='color:red;'>Error escriba el nombe del Dominio</strong>");
            } else {
                // Si cargamos un gif para indicar la espera de la respuesta 
                $("#loader").html("<img src='img/carga.gif' style='width: 100px; height: 60px'>");
                // Enviamos los datos (Nombre del dominio,Extencion,incremento) mediante AJAX al archivo buscador.php
                $.ajax({
                        url: 'includes/buscador.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        data: {
                            Nomb: $("#Nomb").val(),
                            "Ext": $("#Ext").val(),
                            "Incremento": Incremento
                        },
                    })
                    // Resivimos los resultados de buscador.php y eliminamos el gif
                    .done(function(data) {
                        $("#loader").html("");
                        $("#Mostrar").empty().append(data);
                    })
                    //Si falla la operacion mandamos un mensaje mediante consola
                    .fail(function() {
                        console.log("error");
                    })

                    .always(function() {
                        console.log("complete");
                    });
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Y este es mi codigo PHP

```html
<?php 
    //La funcion Whois utiliza 2 parametos: $whois donde almacenaremos el nombre del servidor WOIS y $dominio  
    function Whois($whois='',$dominio){

      $stringDatoWois="";
      $Mostrar =array();
      //Con la el método fsockopen se abre una conexión vía sockets a Internet
      //lo cual devuelve un puntero
      $sock = fsockopen($whois, 43);

      //Determinamos la conexion
      //Si la conexión no se realiza correctamente
      //se imprime el mensaje de error, por otro lado 
      //se accede a los datos.
      
      if(!$sock){

        $Mostrar[0]=false;

      }else{

        $Mostrar[0]=true;
         //Con el método fwrite() escribimos el contenido del del dominio apuntado por el sokect
         //que devuelve un puntero a fichero.
        fwrite($sock, $dominio."\r\n");
        // hacemos un bucle para ir al final del archivo
        while(!feof($sock) ){
          //Recuperamos el método fgets las líneas desde el puntero al fichero.
          $stringDatoWois .= fgetss($sock,128);
        }
        //Se cierra la conexión al sockect de Internet
        fclose($sock);
        $Mostrar[1]=$stringDatoWois;   
      } 
      return $Mostrar;   

    }

    // la variable  $WoisNombre en un array bidimencional que almancena la extencion del dominio junto el URL del servidor WOIS
    $WoisNombre = array(
      '.com'   =>array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),//.com
      '.net'   =>array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),// .net
      '.bo'    =>array('whois.nic.bo','whois.nic.bo solo acepta consultas con dominios .bo'),//.bo
      '.mx'    =>array('whois.nic.mx','No_Se_Encontro_El_Objeto'),//.mx
      '.pe'    =>array('whois.nic.pe','No Object Found'),//.pe
      '.co'    =>array('whois.nic.co','Not found'), //.co
      '.name'  =>array('whois.nic.name','No match'), //.name
      '.org'   =>array('whois.pir.org','Not found')//.org
    );
    //Confirmamos si las variables enviados con AJAX no esten vacias y las guardamos 
    $NombreDominio    =empty($_POST['Nomb']) ? false :  $_POST['Nomb'];
    $ExtesionDominio  =empty($_POST['Ext'])  ? false :  $_POST['Ext'];
    $incremento       =empty($_POST['Incremento']) ? false :  $_POST['Incremento'];

    if(strlen($NombreDominio)>0){

      $stringParser="";
      $NombreDominio   = preg_replace(array('/www./','/http:\//','/\//','/.com/','/.bo/','/.com.bo/','/edu.bo/','/.org.bo/','/.net/','/.mx/','/.name/','/.pe/','/.co/','/.org/'), '', $NombreDominio);

      foreach ($WoisNombre as $key => $value) {

        if($key==$ExtesionDominio){

          if (Whois($value[0],$NombreDominio.$ExtesionDominio)[0]==true){
            //Guardamos todos los datos en una variable y guardamos 2 mensajes de respuesta al usuario, uno si esta disponlible el dominio o si no lo esta
            $DatoSWois= Whois($value[0],$NombreDominio.$ExtesionDominio)[1];
            $Disponible='El dominio '.$NombreDominio.$ExtesionDominio.'<strong> esta disponible.</strong><br>';
            $NoDisponible='El dominio '.$NombreDominio.$ExtesionDominio.'<strong> no esta disponible.</strong><br>';

            //Quitamos algunos caracteres
            //del servidor WHOIS Boliviano
            if($key==".bo"){

              $DatoSWois=str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), '', $DatoSWois);

              if($DatoSWois==$value[1]){

                  echo $Disponible;
              }else{

                  echo $NoDisponible; 
              }
            }else{
              //Buscamos 
              if (preg_match("/".$value[1]."/i",$DatoSWois)){

                echo $Disponible ;
              }else{

                echo $NoDisponible; 
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }       
    }    
?>
```

el codigo funciona pero repito solo me funciona en el primer form y quiero que funcione para ambos

Comment: El problema es que al tener la misma id (cosa que no se debe de hacer), al detectar el coger el elemento por id siempre te coge el primero que encuentra. Para que te funciones bien, prodrías  ponerle la misma clase a los dos botones y asignarles el on click a estas clases.

Comment: Si los **form** son iguales y han de ser procesados de la misma manera, no le veo el sentido a que los tengas en diferentes **form**. ¿O es que quieres que cada uno se pueda enviar por separado? Según das a entender parece que no, que quieres que se envíen todos a la vez.

Comment: Mencionas `AJAX` pero no muestras el javascript que usas. El script `PHP` no intenta recuperar datos múltiples procedentes de **n** formularios ¿que formato de datos esperas recibir?